# access denied adding a data source from ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, ssrs-2014

I have a problem with SSRS 2014. I am trying to browse to a data source on my server see pic0. I then get the error in pic1. I cannot browse to it in IE either pic2. Pic3 is from the site settings page of the SSRS and the 3rd user is me with the roles of System Admin, System User.

Could anyone tell me the setting I am missing to grant me access to this?

Thanks

[image: Pic0]

[image: pic 1]

[image: Pic2]

[image: Pic3]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [pre-defined security roles for SSRS 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). The permission you need to work through report builder is the "Report Builder" role. You should probably also get the publisher role so you can manage deployments and such.